# IF condition statement that write in between sql in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

i have wrote a if condition statement in C# with SQL code to update , delete and insert the data.

i have facing the problem is the data will not be delete from the table.

The condition is if  the Qty is null or 0 then delete from the db table, kindly advise, thank you.

```
public void insertData(string str1, string str2, string str3, string str4, string str5, string str6, string str7, string str8, string str9, string str10, string str11, string str12)
{
    string Qty = Inv_Qty.Text;
    string Inv_ID = WMItem.SelectedValue;
    string FromLoc = Inv_FromLoc.SelectedValue;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    string UpdateWMMRSQL = "UPDATE [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[OTH_INV_QTY_LOC] SET INV_QTY = INV_QTY - '" + Qty + "' WHERE INV_ID = '" + Inv_ID + "' AND INV_LOCATION = '" + FromLoc + "' ";

    string sql = "INSERT INTO OTH_INV_TRANSACTION (INV_TRANS_ID,INV_ID,INV_TRANS_LOCATION,INV_TRANS_QTY,INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR,INV_TRANS_REFNO,INV_TRANS_REMARK,INV_REASON_ID,INV_REASON_REMARK,INV_CREATE_DATE,INV_CREATE_USER,INV_FROMLOC) VALUES  ('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "','" + str4 + "','" + str5 + "','" + str6 + "','" + str7 + "','" + str8 + "','" + str9 + "','" + str10 + "','" + str11 + "','" + str12 + "')";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(UpdateWMMRSQL, con);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    if (Qty == "0")
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        con2.Open();

        string DeleteWMMRSQL = "DELETE FROM [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[OTH_INV_QTY_LOC] WHERE INV_ID = '" + Inv_ID + "' AND INV_LOCATION = '" + FromLoc + "' ";

        SqlCommand cmddelete = new SqlCommand(DeleteWMMRSQL, con2);

        cmddelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con2.Close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1:** you are only checking wether `Qty` is `Zero` or not but as per your requirement you need to also check for `null` ,`Whitespace` and `Empty` aswell.

**Solution 1:** you can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` function to check wether given `String` is `NULL` or `WhiteSpace` or `EMPTY`.

Replace This:

```
if (Qty == "0")
```

with This:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Qty) || Qty.Trim().Equals("0"))
```

**Problem 2:**  you have enclosed single quotes around `INT` Column `INV_ID` .

**Solution 2:**  you do not need to enclose `single quotes` around the `INT` columns.

Replace this:

```
string DeleteWMMRSQL = "DELETE FROM [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[OTH_INV_QTY_LOC] WHERE INV_ID = '" + Inv_ID + "' AND INV_LOCATION = '" + FromLoc + "' ";
```

With this:

```
string DeleteWMMRSQL = "DELETE FROM [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[OTH_INV_QTY_LOC] WHERE INV_ID = " + Inv_ID + " AND INV_LOCATION = '" + FromLoc + "' ";
```

**Suggestion :** your query is open to `SQL injection attacks`, i would suggest you to use `parameterised sql queries` to avoid them.

**Delete Code:** Using `parameterised queries`

```
 if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Qty) || Qty.Trim().Equals("0"))
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        con2.Open();

        string DeleteWMMRSQL = "DELETE FROM [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[OTH_INV_QTY_LOC] WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION";

        SqlCommand cmddelete = new SqlCommand(DeleteWMMRSQL, con2);
        cmddelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_ID",Inv_ID);
        cmddelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_LOCATION",FromLoc);
        cmddelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con2.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Dear Sudhakar Tillapudi, thank for reply and advise, i have changed the code and run the code, but the problem still remain the same. Kindly assist

Comment: @CaulsonChua: could you please debug your code and let me know the error and contents inside `Qty` variable

Comment: Dear Sudhakar Tillapudi, the code i debug show that if 0 or null, it will not delete the item.

Comment: @CaulsonChua: it will not delete means? does it throw any error?